# How to access selected project in Solution Explorer from a Visual Studio Add-In?

Tags: visual-studio, add-in, projects-and-solutions, vsx

I developed a VS 2008 add-in and added a custom menu item to context menu for "Project" nodes in Solution Explorer.

This allows me to right-click any project in solution and perform a custom operation on that project. Or at least, **it would, if I knew how to access the selected project from my Click event handler**.

Can someone with more experience please help me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think what you're looking for is [DTE.ActiveSolutionProjects](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/envdte._dte.activesolutionprojects.aspx).

Comment: Wow, I managed to completely overlook this due to IMHO a poor choice of API name. Thanks!

Comment: But is there an EVENT that notifies one of changes?