# I Want to access Selected Class or Interface When Right Click to project after add in new item to vs 2010

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio-addins

I do this Code:

```
   `public void OnConnection(object application, ext_ConnectMode connectMode, object addInInst, ref Array custom)
                {           
    _applicationObject = (DTE2)application;
                _addInInstance = (AddIn)addInInst;

                if(connectMode == ext_ConnectMode.ext_cm_UISetup)
                {
                    object[] contextGUIDS = new object[] { };
                    Commands2 commands = (Commands2)_applicationObject.Commands;

                    CommandBar SECommandBar = ((CommandBars)_applicationObject.CommandBars)["Context Menus"];
                    CommandBarPopup SEPopUps = (CommandBarPopup)SECommandBar.Controls["Project and Solution Context Menus"];
                    CommandBarPopup oCommandBar = (CommandBarPopup)SEPopUps.Controls["Project"];

                    CommandBarControl oControl = (CommandBarControl)
                      oCommandBar.Controls.Add(MsoControlType.msoControlButton,
                      System.Reflection.Missing.Value,
                      System.Reflection.Missing.Value, 1, true);
                    // Set the caption of the menuitem
                    oControl.Caption = "Create Documentation";

                     oSubMenuItemHandler = _applicationObject.Events.get_CommandBarEvents(oControl) as CommandBarEventsClass;
                    oSubMenuItemHandler.Click+=new _dispCommandBarControlEvents_ClickEventHandler(oSubMenuItemHandler_Click);
}

 protected void oSubMenuItemHandler_Click(object CommandaBarControl,ref bool handled, ref bool cancelDefault)
        {
// I Want to access object of selected class or interface
            MessageBox.Show("Test");                
        }`
```

I'm Develop Add In to reflect all data of class in vs 2010.
Please I want to access selected class or Interface to Reflect all member data.
any one help me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the active [`Project`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/envdte.project_members(v=vs.80).aspx) as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1272022/314334), then get its [`ProjectItems`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/envdte.projectitems_members(v=vs.80).aspx) and for each [`ProjectItem`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/envdte.projectitem_members(v=vs.80).aspx) its [`FileCodeModel`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/envdte.filecodemodel_members(v=vs.80).aspx) and then iterate over its [`CodeElements`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/envdte.codeelements_members(v=vs.80).aspx) with [`Kind`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/envdte.codeelement.kind(v=vs.80).aspx)`= vsCMElementInterface` to get the Interfaces defined there

**Example**:

```
// Container for results
List<string> classes = new List<string> ();
List<string> interfaces = new List<string> ();

// Get selected projects from solution explorer
Array projects = (Array)_applicationObject.ActiveSolutionProjects;

// Get all ProjectItems inside of the selected Projects
var projectItems = projects
    .OfType<Project> ()
    .Where ( p => p.ProjectItems != null )
    .SelectMany ( p => p.ProjectItems.OfType<ProjectItem> ().Where ( pi => pi.FileCodeModel != null ) );

// Iterate over all of these ProjectItems 
foreach ( ProjectItem projectItem in projectItems )
{
    // Get all of the CodeElements (Interfaces and Classes) inside of the current ProjectItem (recursively)
    var elements = projectItem.FileCodeModel.CodeElements
        .OfType<CodeElement> ()
        .SelectMany ( ce => this.GetCodeElements ( ce ) );

    // Do something with the CodeElements that were found
    classes.AddRange ( elements.Where ( el => el.Kind == vsCMElement.vsCMElementClass ).Select ( el => el.Name ) );
    interfaces.AddRange ( elements.Where ( el => el.Kind == vsCMElement.vsCMElementInterface).Select ( el => el.Name ) );
}


// Possible implementation of GetCodeElements:
private IEnumerable<CodeElement> GetCodeElements ( CodeElement root )
{
    List<CodeElement> result = new List<CodeElement> ();
    if ( root == null )
        return result;

    // If the current CodeElement is an Interface or a class, add it to the results
    if ( root.Kind == vsCMElement.vsCMElementClass || root.Kind == vsCMElement.vsCMElementInterface )
    {
        result.Add ( root );
    }

    // Check children recursively
    if ( root.Children != null && root.Children.Count > 0 )
    {
        foreach ( var item in root.Children.OfType<CodeElement> () )
        {
            result.AddRange ( this.GetCodeElements ( item ) );
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I do this code:  `object[] ps=(object[])_applicationObject.ActiveSolutionProjects;

           foreach (Project pr in ps)
           {
               ProjectItems _ProjectItems = pr.ProjectItems;
               CodeModel hh=  _ProjectItems.ContainingProject.CodeModel;
               CodeElements els = hh.CodeElements;
               

           }` i cant access classes and interfaces of project

Comment: I updated my answer with a working example

Comment: Thanks Stephan Bauer it works but can i access class and get its type to do that :`MethodInfo[] mi= obj.GetType().GetMethods();` // obj i get it from selected project

Comment: Thanks Stephan Bauer it works but can i access class and get its type to do that :MethodInfo[] mi= obj.GetType().GetMethods(); // obj i get it from selected project

Comment: I think you shouldn't use reflection here but modify the code above to get the methods inside of your classes/interfaces (just check for the correct `Kind`).