# How to get Type of Selected class from _applicationObject

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2010

This is my code:

```
    public void OnConnection(object application, ext_ConnectMode connectMode, object addInInst, ref Array custom)
        {
            _applicationObject = (DTE2)application;
            _addInInstance = (AddIn)addInInst;
            if (connectMode == ext_ConnectMode.ext_cm_UISetup)
            {
                object[] contextGUIDS = new object[] { };
                Commands2 commands = (Commands2)_applicationObject.Commands;

                CommandBar SECommandBar = ((CommandBars)_applicationObject.CommandBars)["Context Menus"];
                CommandBarPopup SEPopUps = (CommandBarPopup)SECommandBar.Controls["Project and Solution Context Menus"];
                CommandBarPopup ooCommandBar = (CommandBarPopup)SEPopUps.Controls["Project"];
                CommandBarPopup oCommandBar = (CommandBarPopup)SEPopUps.Controls["Item"];



                CommandBarControl oControl = (CommandBarControl)
                  oCommandBar.Controls.Add(MsoControlType.msoControlButton,
                  System.Reflection.Missing.Value,
                  System.Reflection.Missing.Value, 1, true);
                // Set the caption of the menuitem
                oControl.Caption = "Create Documentation";

                oSubMenuItemHandler = _applicationObject.Events.get_CommandBarEvents(oControl) as CommandBarEventsClass;
                oSubMenuItemHandler.Click += new _dispCommandBarControlEvents_ClickEventHandler(oSubMenuItemHandler_Click);


            }
        }

 public void oSubMenuItemHandler_Click(object CommandaBarControl, ref bool handled, ref bool cancelDefault)
        {
SelectedItems doc = _applicationObject.SelectedItems;
// i want to get type of selected Class
}
```

Can I do thing like this.
any one help me to access type of selected Class to make Reflection and Get All Methods and Attributes

Comment: A `.cs` file can contain zero to inifinite amount of classes. Please explain what you are trying to do, not what you think your solution to that is.

Comment: read the file, its essentially a textfile. Just remember your file won't be in a released project (most likely) and I'm not quite sure why you would want to expose the cs file if you were to include it

Comment: The file has no bearing on the types within.

Comment: @Sayse - because i develop Add In to vs 2010 and i want when right click to class get its type to make reflection

Comment: reflection of what? there is no object there to reflect

Comment: @Sayse look at (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18335228/i-want-to-access-selected-class-or-interface-when-right-click-to-project-after-a)

Comment: @Sayse I modified the code above

Answer (score 3):

CS *file name* has no any relation to the *type*(s) present in it.

This is not a `Java` where compiler pretends to have a one class per file and class named as file itself (if I'm not mistaken).

So, no, you can not do that in `C#`.

If you need to read a `C#` coded file, you can have a [Roslyn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vstudio/roslyn.aspx) to make that for you:

- read a file
- construct AST
- return to you types inside that file.

Can have a look here [Read a .cs file, add property to class, write back to .cs file](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/f148d0e6-50c5-4666-ac45-adfcbee3a469/read-a-cs-file-add-property-to-class-write-back-to-cs-file) for concrete example.

Comment: I develop AddIn vs 2010 and when Right click to class and choose my item and in implementation of item click there is System._ComObject return to me but i can't cast it to selected class

Comment: I modified the code above

Answer (score 0):

In order to do this you would have to programmatically compile the .cs file, which is no small task.

There's a decent msdn article on it : ["How to programmatically compile code using C# compiler"](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/304655/en-us)

Once compiled you could use reflection to get the type(s) from the generated assembly : ["Assembly.GetTypes Method"](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.assembly.gettypes.aspx)